# How to export a type that can be an object or a boolean without throwing undefined property errors?

Tags: typescript, types, react-typescript

Hi I want to create a type like this :

```
export type LoginResult = {
    readonly token: string;
    readonly renewal_token: string;
} | boolean;
```

But when a declare a constant as this type, and need to access to token or renewal it throws:

```
Property 'token' does not exist on type 'LoginResult'.
  Property 'token' does not exist on type 'false'.ts(2339)
```

How can I do this ? Is there any other better way to achieve this?
Thank you.

Comment: what is the purpose of defining an interface that defines a boolean and an object? this is in fact what typescript warns you. when defining a variable of your interface, this variable ciuls have two very different types. In other words Boolean doesnt contain token... You need to redesign your interface. why not simply adding a boolean property in your interface? if true, then token is populated, if false no.

Comment: Currently I have it like you say, with a boolean in the object, but I wanted to know if this could be achieved.